# Table Designing dynamically

Tags: php, html

I have a table in the database and getting the output in my php file like

I have a table 'course' in my database

```
id  semester   channel             course             coursecode       grade
1   Sem1      Channel1      Digital Networks             C70089          A
2   Sem1      Channel1      Network Theory               N00089          A+
3   Sem1      Channel2      Data & Structur              D70089          B
4   Sem1      Channel2      Object Oriented              C70089          A
5   Sem2      Channel1      Micro Processors             M70089          A
6   Sem2      Channel1      Electricals                  EE0089          B+
7   Sem2      Channel2      Elect & Communs              EC7080          C
8   Sem2      Channel2      Elect Labs                   LEO90           B+
```

How could I display dynamically either by table or div or ul. Could anyone suggest me simple way to do this designing

I think this is a silly question, as I tried in all the ways, I have come up here

```
   Sem1                                        Sem2
Channell                                       Channell
     Course       Course Code  Grade        Course            Course Code  Grade
Digital Networks    C70089     A           Micro Processors    -------      ---
Network Theory      N00089     A+          Electricals         -------      ---

Channel2                                       Channel2
Course            Course Code  Grade        Course            Course Code  Grade
Data & Structur     D70089     B           Elect & Communs       -----     -----
Object Oriented     C70089     A           Elect Labs            -----     -----
```

Comment: I would use `<ul>` or `<dl><dd><dt>` tags inside of divs with `style="display:inline";` or `style="float:left";`. Not posting this as an answer because I haven't tested any of it...just a suggestion for you to try. I definitely would **not** use a `<table>` because you're not displaying it in a tabular format. `SectionC` under `Course A` has no relation to `SectionC` under `Course C`. If the data for `SectionC` under `Course A` is really long and goes on multiple lines, you don't want it to push down `SectionD` under `Course C`.

Comment: Thank You I tried this and how could it happen dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `mysqli_*` functions, your solution might look like this:

**[CODEPAD](http://codepad.org/ryWHoHMh)** - gives you your HTML.
**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Eha4j/)** - styles your generated HTML, showing the end result.

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM course ORDER BY semester, channel');
$semester = $channel = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    if ($row["semester"] !== $semester)
    {
        if ($semester !== "")
        {
            echo "    </table>\n";
            echo "</div>\n";
        }

        $semester = $row["semester"];
        $channel = $row["channel"];

        echo "<div class=\"semester\">\n";
        echo "    <h3>{$semester}</h3>\n";
        echo "    <h3>{$channel}</h3>\n";
        echo "    <table>\n";
        echo "        <tr>\n";
        echo "            <th>Course</th>\n";
        echo "            <th>Course Code</th>\n";
        echo "            <th>Grade</th>\n";
        echo "        </tr>\n";
    }

    if ($row["channel"] !== $channel)
    {
        $channel = $row["channel"];

        echo "    </table>\n";
        echo "    <br />\n";
        echo "    <h3>{$channel}</h3>\n";
        echo "    <table>\n";
        echo "        <tr>\n";
        echo "            <th>Course</th>\n";
        echo "            <th>Course Code</th>\n";
        echo "            <th>Grade</th>\n";
        echo "        </tr>\n";
    }

    echo "        <tr>\n";
    echo "            <td>{$row["course"]}</td>\n";
    echo "            <td>{$row["coursecode"]}</td>\n";
    echo "            <td>{$row["grade"]}</td>\n";
    echo "        </tr>\n";
}

if ($semester !== "")
{
    echo "    </table>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

Comment: @karthik: OK, but your sample doesn't work the way you want. It puts everything into one list. Was there something wrong with the solution I provided? From what I can see, the only thing you need to do is perform your query, and since you're using `mysql_*` functions (which you really shouldn't be, [PHP discourages using them](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)), you would just need to change `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Don't use `mysql_fetch_array()` unless you actually want the result as **both** a numerically-indexed array and an associative array.

Comment: By the way, jsFiddle isn't really good for PHP code. It's more for client-side code, like Javascript, CSS, and HTML. Use [codepad](http://codepad.org/) for PHP.

Comment: Ya sure - I have tried this code in codepad - http://codepad.org/pNrb8K8l  - it was displaying onebyone, but I need all semesters sidebyside

Comment: It was showing a Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given on line 149.  Could you please suggest me

Comment: You should perform your query using mysql_query and store it in $query, then pass that as the parameter to mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: Ya that I solved, but I need all the courses to be displayed side by side but not one by one

Comment: And the code you provided - it was displaying only one section under a each course, it should display all the sections it has

Comment: The code that I provided in [this example](http://codepad.org/qwMc2fsI) produces [this output](http://codepad.org/qwMc2fsI#output), which has multiple sections under each course. I put in a placeholder class named `course`, which you are meant to use to get them to display side by side. Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukUG6/) for an example of how to do that.

Comment: Yes, but the problem I am facing was the display part, where the code you provided. Could you please see the updated question above where I have given a complete database structure and output. This is my tried code  http://codepad.org/OYvfGwcK - Here the problem I was facing is displays the table headers repaeatedly, but I need only one table for one channel.

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look. Here is the [PHP code](http://codepad.org/ryWHoHMh) to generate your HTML (notice I added an `ORDER BY` to your query). And here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eha4j/) that shows it styled similarly to the way you are asking. I switched to tables since you are now displaying the data in a more tabular format. It makes more sense to use a table for this.